# Flash games on Google App Engine crash (Some of them)

Tags: flash, google-app-engine, crash

I have some problems about some of the flash games that don't run correctly on my Google App Engine app. One of them crashes every time and another just stop working, however, these problems don't occur when the same versions of the flash games are running on normal web hosting service (non-GAE) with identical flash embedding tags.

The game on my website that is running on Google App Engine and crashes but working fine when it is running on a standard hosting server.
http://www.eeriegames.com/play-game/the-breach

The game on my website that is running on Google App Engine and doesn't work but working fine when it is running on a standard web hosting server.
http://www.eeriegames.com/play-game/yan-loong-legend-3-double-swallow

Thank you very much for your help. I have tried adding crossdomain.xml policy file and change embedding tags with various parameters but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

I just clicked on your eeriegames link for The Breach and it didn't run (Windows 7 PC, IE9, Flash Player 11.5) - I got the "out of memory" exclamation mark icon. So I'm wondering whether this is anything to do with memory settings or similar.
Having said that, I think the OOM icon appears when the player has died regardless of the reason...
Your SWF works okay when I download it and run it in the external Flash Player - but when I tried looking at this in Adobe's SWF Investigator it gave me some parse errors. So I'm thinking perhaps the SWF is corrupted somehow. What did you use to compile it? Looks like Flex 3.. might be worth using something more recent?
Not quite sure why this would work on one system and not another though, or why I get the OOM icon when I use your webservers whereas for you this works fine. Have you also checked your global Flash settings to make sure trusted paths, local storage etc are all set up the same for both sites?
My suggestion would be to try to get the SWF to compile so that you don't get any parse errors when looking at it using a decompiler, and then see if you still have a problem.
Hope that helps!
Andrew

Comment: Thanks Andrew but I can't compile these games because I am not the developers of these games. I just basically host games on my app running on GAE. The strange thing is that these games run smoothly on non-GAE web hosting. I really can't identify the cause of this problem.